# JMenu - Submenus won't display

Tags: java, submenu, jmenu, jmenuitem

I just began using JMenu. When the buttons are clicked, I want the menu to display a submenu category, like a dropbox.

So my question is, "Why isn't the submenu visible?"

Please look below for the relevant code.

```
    // Frame title
    frame = new JFrame(NAME);
    frame.setSize(350, 250);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // Add menu bar
    JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();


    // 1.0 Site Menu, S
    JMenu siteMenu = new JMenu("Site");
    siteMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    mb.add(siteMenu);

    // 1.1 Site->Website, W
    JMenuItem websiteMenu = new JMenuItem("Website", KeyEvent.VK_W);
    mb.add(websiteMenu);

    // 1.2 Site->Forum, F
    JMenuItem forumMenu = new JMenuItem("Forum", KeyEvent.VK_F);
    mb.add(forumMenu);

    // 2.0 Gallery Menu, G
    JMenu galleryMenu = new JMenu("Gallery");
    galleryMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_G);
    mb.add(galleryMenu);

    // 2.1 Gallery->Custom Skins, C
    JMenuItem skinsMenu = new JMenuItem("Custom Skins", KeyEvent.VK_C);
    mb.add(skinsMenu);

    // 3.0 Screenshot Menu, S
    JMenu screenshotMenu = new JMenu("Screenshot");
    screenshotMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    mb.add(screenshotMenu);


    // Sets the menubar for this frame
    frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
```

I have tried to lookup the issue, but I just can't seem to locate it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the `JMenuItem` objects directly to the `JMenuBar`. Try adding them to your `JMenu` objects instead:

```
// 1.0 Site Menu, S
JMenu siteMenu = new JMenu("Site");
siteMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
mb.add(siteMenu);

// 1.1 Site->Website, W
JMenuItem websiteMenu = new JMenuItem("Website", KeyEvent.VK_W);
siteMenu.add(websiteMenu);

// 1.2 Site->Forum, F
JMenuItem forumMenu = new JMenuItem("Forum", KeyEvent.VK_F);
siteMenu.add(forumMenu);

// and so on
```

Comment: Hmm, it works on my device. See if moving `frame.setVisible(true)` to after `frame.setJMenuBar(mb)` helps.